# Chartjs defaults deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am setting the following default in Chartjs (v2.9.3) to alter the default look of my bar charts:

```
Chart.defaults.bar.scales.xAxes[0].categoryPercentage = .95;
```

This causes the following deprecation warnings:

```
bar chart: "scales.[x/y]Axes.categoryPercentage" is deprecated. Please use "dataset.categoryPercentage" instead
```

But I can't get that to work, amongst others I have tried:

```
Chart.defaults.bar.dataset.categoryPercentage = 1;
Chart.defaults.bar.datasets[0].categoryPercentage = 1;
Chart.defaults.global.bar.dataset.categoryPercentage = 1;
Chart.defaults.global.bar.datasets[0].categoryPercentage = 1;
```

Is there a good resource to find the right commands to set defaults? Unfortunately, the otherwise excellent documentation is very incomplete in this regard.

The above isn't the only default setting I am struggling with.

For example, the following doesn't do anything (even though `Chart.defaults.global.hover.animationDuration = 50;` works):

```
Chart.defaults.global.hover.mode = 'index';
Chart.defaults.global.hover.intersect = true;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for globally changing the bar `categoryPercentage` is the following:

```
Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.categoryPercentage = 0.95;
```

And here's a working sample:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.datasets.bar.categoryPercentage = 0.95;

var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
    datasets: [{
            label: "Occurrences", 
            data: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)"],
            borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
};
var option = {
 scales: {
   yAxes:[{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
    }]
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data:data,
  options:option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

> To find out about other valid options contained in `Chart.defaults`, simply log it to the console (`console.log(Chart.defaults)`) and search for the option name.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set it globally, I actually recommend you to set it for each chart according to [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#example-dataset-configuration).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var data = {
  labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Occurrences",
    data: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6],
    fill: false,
    backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)", "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)", "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)", "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)"],
    borderColor: ["rgb(255, 99, 132)", "rgb(255, 159, 64)", "rgb(255, 205, 86)", "rgb(75, 192, 192)", "rgb(54, 162, 235)"],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

var option = {
  datasets: {
    bar: {
      categoryPercentage: 0.95
    }
  },
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```